# In Azure DevOps with a Multi Stage Pipeline, how do a manually deploy to an environment?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task, azure-yaml-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines

I currently have a separate Pipeline for a Build and Deployments.

The SysTest deployment is triggered automatically.

I manually deploy to QA, which I like (See below).

[image]

I am trying to upgrade this process to a Multi Stage Pipeline.

However, I can't find a way to just deploy to QA manually.  The best of found is to Review and Approve the deployment to QA. (See below) Which is not really what I want.

Is there a way to just manually deploy to an environment with in a Multi Stage Pipeline?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not at present. It's one of the areas that's lacking feature parity at the moment; you can't skip stages or have a stage be manual-only.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I spent sometime searching for a resolution to this problem and came to the same conclusion. So, this afternoon I set up a Multi Stage Pipeline for the Build and Systest.  Then updated my Release Pipeline for QA.  Not a perfect solution but it seems like a step in the right direction.  Thanks again.